# Статическая линковка WinForm

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, clr

Я студент университета. Мне дали задание разработать программу с GUI которая работала на компьютере без установки дополнительных ресурсов(допустим Java не подходит так как ее нужно устанавливать). Программу написал с помощью C++ и CLR(WinForm), но вылезла проблема. Для программы нужны .dll которые поставляются с .Net. Была идея использовать статическую линковку(среда Visual Studio 2017), но среда отказывается из-за CLR. Можно ли это как то обойти и всё таки связать статически?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework является компонентом Windows, поэтому статическая компоновка не нужна. Вам нужно лишь поставлять разные версии для разных ОС (Win7 содержит .NET 3.5, а последующие версии - .NET 4.0+). Плохая новость заключается в том, что [для сборки С++/CLI под .NET 3.5 необходим набор инструментов от Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18681240/8674428)).

Конечно, приложение на С++/CLI помимо .NET Framework зависит также от Visual C++ Runtime, но его можно просто распространять вместе с приложением (поместить msvcpxxx.dll в каталог с программой). См. например [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019). Статическая компоновка чего-либо в 99% случаев - плохая идея, так как приводит к раздуванию размеров бинарников и многократной дубликации кода одних и тех же библиотек. Впрочем, сама по себе идея разработки чего-то на WinForms и C++/CLI в 2019 г. не выглядит привлекательно.